# Time outs with crystal report

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, crystal-reports

i have a web page which uses around 10 session variables to store values on a button click.and after assign session values Response.Redirect("~/url",false); to a a page which contains crystal report viewer.and report should show those session values.after keeping the application idle for 45 mins i click on the button which assign session values.then it's redirecting to the report page but the report is not shown(only happens application is idle for nearly 45 mins)

i'm using iis 7

in the web.config i have set sessionState timeout="60" and application pool idle time out to 60 mins.

any idea why this happens

Comment: This is not a session timeout issue as my session is not timing out. This is only happening with the crystal viewer and not all the time. If I restart iis, crystal begins working again. There has to be some disconnect between the cr4vs2010 and iis.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether the Timeout for session is set in your browser... try using an other browser...